# Question about Future execution order in Dart

Tags: dart, future

Here is my code,

```
Future<int> test() {
  print('Start test()');
  for (var i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < 100000; j++) {
      var k = i * j;
    }
  }
  print('After a long running task in test()');
  return Future<int>.value(1);
}

void main() {
  test().then((result) => print('Done with test()'));
  print('Done with main().');
}
```

and here is the output,

```
Start test()
After a long running task in test()
Done with main().
Done with test()
```

my question is, shouldn't 'Done with main()' be printed before 'After a long running task in test()'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Future.microtask()` if you want skip task.

Example:

```dart
Future<int> test() {
  print('Start test()');
  for (var i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < 100000; j++) {
      var k = i * j;
    }
  }
  print('After a long running task in test()');
  return Future<int>.value(1);
}

void main() {
  Future.microtask(test);
  print('Done with main().');
}
```

Output:

```
Done with main().
Start test()
After a long runnin task in test()
```

Comment: Future(test) works too, but i am not quite understand the difference between Future(test) and Future.microtask(test).